# Applying file filter in RadAsync File upload control

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asyncfileupload

How to enforce user to see only those specific types of files which he has allowed while browsing for files to upload through RadAsyncUpload Control .

Answer (score 0):

Only the Silverlight upload module can do that, as otherwise you have no access to the OS in order to filter the File Selection dialog.

Thus, IE8 and IE9 have that OOB, just open this demo in either of them: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

You can force the SL plugin to be the only used plugin with the following code (at your own discretion, you will lose FileAPI for modern browsers):

```
<script>
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.Flash.isAvailable = function () { return false; };
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.Silverlight.isAvailable = function () { return true; };
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable = function () { return false; };
</script>
```